# Oauth token validity

Tags: security, scope, oauth-2.0

I'm facing an issue about the scope of validity of my token :

I have two or more Applications A that use the same Authorization Server.
An Application A User can forge a legit token and extract it to use it with the application B and get access to application B.
My Application B has sensitive data and API so I don't want it to be accessed with a token forged by any other application.

Is there any mechanism that limits the validity of a token .

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

A "real" token would be bound in time and scope but it would typically include an "audience" as well that would tell the recipient a.k.a. the Resource Server whether the token was really issued for it (or someone else). So the mechanism to protect against replay of tokens to another service is generically called "token audience".

OAuth 2.0 itself doesn't define the contents of the token, but if you're using a JWT token the audience would be recorded in the "aud" claim.

On top of that you could use the scope mechanism to define scopes that are only valid/accepted in the context of a particular Resource Server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ....
But I found out that JWT use the "AZP" claim to identify the client application.
So the application just have to check de AZP field if it matchs with its ID , and accept the request .

Comment: the "azp" claim would by definition identify the presenter or Client, not the Resource Server i.e the intended recipient; if a Client obtains more than one access token this is where things start to go wrong